# Filename convention for TimedRotatingFileHandler log? (python)

Tags: python

Python 2.7:
Every time a log experiences a rollover event (logs with a RotatingFileHandler) a 'backup' log is generated.

For instance :

```
logFile = 'general.log'
file_handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(logFile,when="midnight")
```

Results in midnight roll over and on rollover event the following file is created:

```
general.log.2015-01-21
```

Does this module offer any flexibility how these filenames are structured?
ie use a different convention ... `20150121_general.log`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer is no: according to [TimedRotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler) documentation you have no way to do it.

The suffix change based on `when` parameter like you can see in the code https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/logging/handlers.py#l187

From the same source code you can see that override `suffix` is simple but you must override `extMatch` too:

```
class MyTimedRotatingFileHandler(TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyTimedRotatingFileHandler,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.suffix = "%Y%m%d"
        self.extMatch = re.compile(r"^\d{4}\d{2}\d{2}$")
```

Unfortunately replace dot separator and swap `suffix` and `basename` is not so simple and you must rewrite `doRollover()` and `getFilesToDelete()` methods.

A hacking can be something like this (untested)... I hope it works but I cannot give any warrant :)

```
class MyTimedRotatingFileHandler(TimedRotatingFileHandler):

        self.extMatch = r"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$"

   def getFilesToDelete(self):
        """ CUT, PASTE AND .... HACK
        """
        dirName, baseName = os.path.split(self.baseFilename)
        fileNames = os.listdir(dirName)
        result = []
        extMatch = re.compile(r"^\d{4}\d{2}\d{2}$")
        ends = "_" + baseName + ".log"
        elen = len(ends)
        for fileName in fileNames:
            if fileName[-elen:] == ends:
                date = fileName[-elen:]
                if self.extMatch.match(date):
                    result.append(os.path.join(dirName, fileName))
        result.sort()
        if len(result) < self.backupCount:
            result = []
        else:
            result = result[:len(result) - self.backupCount]
        return result

    def doRollover(self):
        """
        CUT AND PAST FROM TimedRotatingFileHandler
        customize file name by prefix instead suffix
        """
        if self.stream:
            self.stream.close()
            self.stream = None
        # get the time that this sequence started at and make it a TimeTuple
        currentTime = int(time.time())
        dstNow = time.localtime(currentTime)[-1]
        t = self.rolloverAt - self.interval
        if self.utc:
            timeTuple = time.gmtime(t)
        else:
            timeTuple = time.localtime(t)
            dstThen = timeTuple[-1]
            if dstNow != dstThen:
                if dstNow:
                    addend = 3600
                else:
                    addend = -3600
                timeTuple = time.localtime(t + addend)
        #################################################
        # THE HACK!!!! ##################################
        ##################################################
        dfn = time.strftime("%Y%m%d", timeTuple) + "_" +self.baseFilename + ".log"
        if os.path.exists(dfn):
            os.remove(dfn)
        # Issue 18940: A file may not have been created if delay is True.
        if os.path.exists(self.baseFilename):
            os.rename(self.baseFilename, dfn)
        if self.backupCount > 0:
            for s in self.getFilesToDelete():
                os.remove(s)
        if not self.delay:
            self.stream = self._open()
        newRolloverAt = self.computeRollover(currentTime)
        while newRolloverAt <= currentTime:
            newRolloverAt = newRolloverAt + self.interval
        #If DST changes and midnight or weekly rollover, adjust for this.
        if (self.when == 'MIDNIGHT' or self.when.startswith('W')) and not self.utc:
            dstAtRollover = time.localtime(newRolloverAt)[-1]
            if dstNow != dstAtRollover:
                if not dstNow:  # DST kicks in before next rollover, so we need to deduct an hour
                    addend = -3600
                else:           # DST bows out before next rollover, so we need to add an hour
                    addend = 3600
                newRolloverAt += addend
        self.rolloverAt = newRolloverAt
```

Comment: is there a prefix field ?

Comment: No :( File name is build in `doRollover()` method at https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/logging/handlers.py#l345 and the code is not designed to be customized.